# Are questions about data integration on topic on this site?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, asking-questions

[*Data integration*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_integration), according to Wikipedia, is

> Data integration involves combining data residing in different sources
>   and providing users with a unified view of them.

So at least part of it seems like an important part for, or before data science. Is it then relevant to ask questions about data integration on this site?

Specifically, I was looking for a seminal/influential but up to date book on data integration giving foundations and overview of methods.

I've looked around on Amazon but could not found a successful<sup>*</sup> book having "data integration" in its title.

If you think it's rather offtopic, which SE site could be more suitable?

Side note: maybe, "data integration" as term has been superseded by "data science"?

[image: r]

Number of editions, customer rating

Comment: I would stick with a "No", cause it has nothing to do with "Data Science". It can be called as the step before data science in a pipeline imho

Comment: thanks; would you say it's rather a StackOverflow topic?

Comment: Yes. It looks more at home on SO or SoftwareEngineering SE, depending on how you structure the question/post :)